# Receiving push notifications on cordova/phonegap application from Parse

Tags: android, cordova, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm developing an android application (iOS too, but not important now) using apache cordova (ionic framework) and Parse.com for backend.

I need to subscribe to push channel and process the received messages in my javascript code.

What's the best way to process this messages?

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm trying to the same thing and have been unsuccessful.

Comment: No solution found.  I decided to create a plugin where I put all my application native code including push notifications management. If you try this solution, you need to implement your own MainApplication class and call the Parse.Init method in the onCreate method.  Main problem in this solution is native and javascript Parse APIs doesn't share current user :-(, but enougth for now...

Comment: You could have a look at a plugin I have forked which does this for you: [mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler](https://github.com/mobiRic/cordova-parse-pushhandler). Original credit goes to [Frosty Elk for their work](https://github.com/FrostyElk/cordova-parse-plugin). It would be great if you wanted to contribute to either repo, as the community needs a good solution to this issue.